# Using QPDF with C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, qpdf

I am attempting to translate this qpdf command:

qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable input.pdf editable.pdf

into the equivalent method calls I would need when using the qpdf dll (available from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdf/).

I ran the qpdf dll through dumpbin to get the function names, and by looking at the header files that were included for use with a c++ project I can see the parameters for the functions.

For example the function needed to impart the --object-streams option above would (from what I can tell) be this function:

```
void setObjectStreamMode(qpdf_object_stream_e);
```

from the c++ header file which becomes:

```
[DllImport("qpdf21.dll")]
static extern void _ZN10QPDFWriter19setObjectStreamModeE20qpdf_object_stream_e(int stateEnum);
```

in the C# file.

The problem is when I use the above function I get an

AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory

error, which makes me think I need to create a QPDF object somehow, but I have never used object oriented pinvokes, so I'm at a loss of how to make the object accessible in c#.

If anyone is already familiar with using the dll in C#, or even in C++, and could tell me the correct functions to call to replicate the command I would appreciate it!

Comment: I'll remove the edit and answer the question after I solve that memory issue.

Comment: found the issue, I had the pinvoke for cleanup wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to figure it out, the below code replicates the command, turns out I was looking into the wrong header file:

```
[DllImport("qpdf21.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern IntPtr qpdf_init();

[DllImport("qpdf21.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void qpdf_cleanup(ref IntPtr qpdfData);

[DllImport("qpdf21.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int qpdf_read(IntPtr qpdfdata, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string fileName, IntPtr password);

[DllImport("qpdf21.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void qpdf_set_object_stream_mode(IntPtr qpdf, int mode);

[DllImport("qpdf21.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void qpdf_set_qdf_mode(IntPtr qpdf, int value);

[DllImport("qpdf21.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int qpdf_init_write(IntPtr qpdf, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string fileName);

[DllImport("qpdf21.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int qpdf_write(IntPtr qpdf);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //call init
    IntPtr qpdfData = qpdf_init();

    //call read (which gets and processes the input file)
    //0 result == good
    int result = qpdf_read(qpdfData, @"scan.pdf", IntPtr.Zero);

    //call init_write
    result = qpdf_init_write(qpdfData, @"scanEditable.pdf");

    //set write options
    //disable object stream mode
    qpdf_set_qdf_mode(qpdfData, 1);
    qpdf_set_object_stream_mode(qpdfData, 0);

    //call write
    result = qpdf_write(qpdfData);

    //call cleanup
    qpdf_cleanup(ref qpdfData);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've figured out a good answer here. You've discovered the C API, which is intended for helping to use QPDF from languages other than C++ through the DLL. The C API is primarily documented in the [qpdf-c.h header file](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/blob/master/include/qpdf/qpdf-c.h). You can find some information in the [Using Other Languages section of the manual](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html#ref.using.other-languages) as well. The C API does not expose the full functionality of qpdf's C++ library. If you find missing pieces, please feel free to create an issue at [github](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/issues). I try to update the C API when I add new interfaces, but I don't do it for every interface, and some of the functionality in the CLI is implemented directly in the tool and doesn't map to a single library function.

If the C API is not rich enough for your use case, it's also possible to write your own C++ class with some functions declared `extern "C"`, export them, and build an additional DLL that you can use in the manner you have found above. You can look at [qpdf-c.cc](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/blob/master/libqpdf/qpdf-c.cc) as an example of how this works.